# MVC tabs second tab not loading properly after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs

I have three tabs.  Tabs 2 and 3 loads a partial view with a form to post via ajax. The 2nd tab posts fine and returns to 2nd tab afterwards, but the 3rd tab requires I hit the browser refresh button before the ajax works, otherwise, ajax does not work and it just posts via html.beginform() and just loads the partialview without the _layout.chstml after posting.  Why do I have to hit the refresh before ajax works?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>        
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">General</a></li>            
            <li>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Items", "Item", "Test", null, null)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Total", "Total", "Test", null, null)
            </li>                         
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1">
        1st tab data here...
        </div>


</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //initialize tabs plugin with listening on activate event
        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({           
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                //get the active tab index
                var active = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");

                //save it to cookies
                $.cookie("activeTabIndex", active);

            }
        });

        //read the cookie
        var activeTabIndex = $.cookie("activeTabIndex");        

        //make active needed tab
        if (activeTabIndex !== undefined) {
            tabs.tabs("option", "active", activeTabIndex);
        }                     

    });

</script>
```

Tab 2  partial view loaded from controller

```
@model Mvc.Models.Test

@using (Html.BeginForm("AjaxItemForm", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm" }))
{

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    <div id="result">
        @Html.Action("ShowTestList", "Test")
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {             

        $(function() {
            $("#frm").on("submit", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        // update DIV with new data
                        $('#result').html(data);                        

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        $('#result').html("error");
                    }                    
                });                               

            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose since jquery on is used you only attach event to one #frm element :)  try .Live

Comment: `.Live()` has been depreciated for several versions now.  `.On()` is the acceptable and preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I was not using unique id for the forms.  On each partialview, I was using the same id for form name.  I also changed each partialview all elements id's to be unique id's and it appears to have fixed the problem.